# Apache mod_wsgi and Qt

Tags: python, apache, qt, mod-wsgi

I'm getting an error in Apache error_log with WSGI and PyQt4 :

```
: cannot connect to X server
```

My Python code looks like :

```
import PyQt4.qtgui as qtgui
__qt_app = qtgui.QApplication([])
```

I had a minimal CentOS installation and I had to install lightweight X server (group "X Window System" and some other rpms).

Previous code is working in a console after the X server installation (before was not).

Environment : CentOS 6.5, Apache 2.2.15, mod_wsgi 4.3.0.

Any clue about what could happening ?

Comment: Are you trying to initialize a Qt Application in a WSGI web application context?
This is not going to work. A webserver has to X session and that would be required for a Qt application.

Comment: Like Klaus, I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Why do you want to use a Qt app within a website? How are you expecting that to work?

Comment: i'd like to parse ui file... So what i do is calling `ui_instance = qtuic.loadUi(ui_file_path)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution", i re-installed minimal CentOS (i don't need X server) and i added the `xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` package.

Start Xvfb on display 99 :

```
/usr/bin/Xvfb :99 -screen 0 640x480x24
```

Edit python code :

```
import os
import PyQt4.qtgui as qtgui

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':99'
__qt_app = qtgui.QApplication([])
```

And everything is working.